# live streaming from IPcamera to wowza server via android device RTSP Android

Tags: android, rtsp, wowza

I am sending live streaming from IP camera to wowza server via android device. here i am stream in device then want to send on server using rtsp.so please provide useful link.

Comment: What kind of IP camera (vendor/model) are you using? Does it support encoding an RTSP stream?

Comment: yes,that support to RTSP and camera model is DS-2CD2410F-IW (Hikevision).so please give me some useful solution so i go ahead.

Comment: @Michelle-B : are you getting my point?

Comment: yes say what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to connect an RTSP camera encoder to your Wowza server, and then play back the output stream on your Android device.

1. Connect your RTSP camera encoder to Wowza.

   Obtain the RTSP URI from your camera encoder and test that this URI is valid by playing it back using a third-party tool such as VLC. Create a stream file that contains this URI. Stream files are text files with a ".stream" extension, and are usually saved in the content/ directory of your Wowza installation path. In the Manager UI, you can connect this stream file to your Wowza software by selecting your application, going into Stream Files, and clicking on the Connect button next to the file.
2. Some things to note about RTSP encoders is that some send unknown tracks which may cause some issues on your Wowza software. You can test adding/removing the following settings to see if they resolve any connection issues. You will need to add them to the /Root/Application/MediaCaster/Properties container (there are several) of your conf/[appName]/Application.xml file.

   ```
   <Property>
   <Name>rtspValidationFrequency</Name>
   <Value>0</Value>
   <Type>Integer</Type>
   </Property>

   <Property>
   <Name>rtspFilterUnknownTracks</Name>
   <Value>true</Value>
   <Type>Boolean</Type>
   </Property>
   ```
3. Play back in an Android device can be either HLS or RTSP.

   http://[wowza-public-ip-address]:1935/live/[streamName]/playlist.m3u8 
   rtsp://[wowza-public-ip-address]:1935/live/[streamName]

   You can test playback using the native player on the Android device. Do note that some older Android models do not support HLS.